# darken the whole tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm programming a game sa my graduation project in school. Once the manager closes the game, I want the other users to have a pop up that the game is ended and a button to click on in order to continue.
I want the **whole** window (with all the widgets) to get darker (not totally black but darker). Everything besides the pop up and the "continue" button

Enyone has a clue what I can do? I searched on the Internet and found nothing :/

Comment: Is that even possible? I mean, you probably could use a canvas or sth. as an overlay, but I'm not even sure about that. Try using pygame or something next time you develop a game, tkinter is not really perfect for that.

Comment: That's the GUI that we learned....

Comment: I can't find a way to do that. Some people recommend using separate windows. I think it is possible to create a semi-transparent window with tk, and the only alternative seems to be just darkening each widget individually

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the main window (use `ImageGrab.grab()` from `Pillow` module),  and use an image tool (`ImageEnhance.Brightness` from `Pillow` module) to darken the screenshot image.  Then overlay the image on top of the main window.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, but that does not seem to be any efficient. That's a bodge, so think twice before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to use `ImageGrab` on linux, here is my solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import time
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def grab(widget):
    box = (widget.winfo_rootx(), widget.winfo_rooty(), widget.winfo_rootx()+widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_rooty()+widget.winfo_height())
    grab = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)
    return grab

def darken(widget):
    widget.overlay = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(np.asanyarray(grab(widget))//2))
    cvs = tk.Canvas(widget, width=widget.winfo_width(), height=widget.winfo_height())
    cvs.place(x=0,y=0)
    cvs.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=widget.overlay)
    return cvs

root = tk.Tk()

def apply_dark():
    cvs = darken(root)
    b = tk.Button(root, text='Ok')
    def d():
        cvs.destroy()
        b.destroy()
    b.config(command=d)
    b.place(x=50, y=10)

tk.Label(root, text='Label1').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text='Label2').grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text='Button1').grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text='Darken', command=apply_dark).grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Fiddle around with this code. Of course this is in fact just a quick bodge (non-reliable, inefficient), but still - works for me.
Hope that's helpful!